# Draw line at the drop position of a node in treeview in Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe5

[image]

As illustrated above, when someone drags a tree node how can I show the drop position as a line in the tree view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might paint your line in then `CustomDrawItem` Event for Nodes which are drop targets.

```
procedure TMyForm.TreeView1CustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomTreeView;
  Node: TTreeNode; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
var
 y:Integer;
begin
   if Node.DropTarget then
    begin
      y := Node.DisplayRect(true).Bottom;
      Sender.Canvas.MoveTo(0,y-1);
      Sender.Canvas.LineTo(Sender.Width,y-1);
      Sender.Canvas.Font.Size :=  10;
    end;
end;
```

If you in addition as taken, from the comments, want to hide the selection you will have to set DefaultDraw to false and paint the text of the node on your own.

```
procedure TMyForm.TreeView1CustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomTreeView;
  Node: TTreeNode; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
Const
  C_WishedAdditional = 10; // addtional lenght to the Node.DisplayRect - width
var
  r: TRect;
begin
  if Node.DropTarget then
  begin
    r := Node.DisplayRect(true);
    Sender.Canvas.MoveTo(r.Left, r.bottom - 2); // start of the line
    Sender.Canvas.Pen.Width := 3; // adjust line width
    Sender.Canvas.Pen.Color := clMaroon; // adjust line color
    Sender.Canvas.LineTo(r.Right + C_WishedAdditional, r.bottom - 2); // end of the line
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
    SetBkMode(Sender.Canvas.Handle,TRANSPARENT); // prevent text background from overpainting
    Sender.Canvas.TextOut(r.Left + 2, r.top + 1 , Node.Text);
    DefaultDraw := false;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: how to hide the highlighting of drop target node?

Comment: its works thank you sir, furthermore how can change line size as illustrated in the image?

Comment: @Azzi I did an edit, sorry did not realize the wished line length.

Comment: Just draw it on the canvas e.g. with Draw or StretchDraw, you will find a lot of examples on this Site.

Comment: haw can change node to draw the line?

Comment: The node is given from the DragOver hence Node.DropTarget. You should describe what you are trying to achieve in your second question, best would be with code describing the expected behavior and what does not work. The DrawEvent is the wrong place to change the desired Node.